# Что нужно для импорта import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

Tags: java, android-studio

Решил подключить к Android проекту библиотеку [Autobahn|Android](http://autobahn.ws/android/), вроде бы скачал с [github](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-android), добавил оба `jar` файла, которые были в **libs**, но всё равно ругается на `import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;`. 
Что за причина может быть? Что нужно ещё, может, подключить?

Comment: вы случайно не под 24 api собираете? если да то обычно надо добавлять `useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'` под `buildToolsVersion` в гредл файле.

Comment: compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'